# How to enter a discounted fee after the discount date for an event

Tags: civievent

Using CiviCRM v4.5.8 with WP v4.2.2 and no Price Set, using Regular Fees and Discounted Fees

We have a 5K Run Event with a discount fee of $20 before June 1 and after that date the fee is $30.  Some of the participants sent in payment via mail.  When we are manually entering them we can not enter the discount amount.  It is defaulting to the amount after June 1.   We are selecting "Advanced Discount" in the Discount set area but it does not change the amount that we can select.   Is this a bug or am I missing something?   THANKS.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your CiviCRM version and whether you are using a price set or the standard fees?

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this involves using a price set. Insert a price field with the value of `-1` called *Discount* that is visible only by Admin. This allows you enter a discount to registrations entered in the back-end without affecting the front-end pricing.

I believe the only way to do this without using a price set is to change your advance discount date, enter your mail-in registrations, and then reset the date. This does run the risk of people getting the discount rate if they register while you are entering the mail-in registrations.

Comment: I'm working on the Price set for this and adding the Admin only field.  Where am I to enter the -1 value and why?  Also, can I change this in the middle of the registration period or will that mess things up?

Comment: When you setup the field make the price  -1. When you enter a qty in the field you will get the discount. It is handy to apply not only discounts after the expiration but also any special discounts you may need to apply.

Comment: Ok I finally got this.  Now, can I switch from the Regular Fees/Discount Set to a Price Set in the middle of the registration period?

Comment: Switching should not be a problem. The line items may display a bit different which may effect line item reports if you are using them.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [CiviDiscount](https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount) module. You can set up a promo code for $10 off, with the code known only to back office users. When adding the registration, apply the code.